# How to skip or end a keyword command when it done in discord.py?

Tags: python

Well, it's mine question again;)

I wrote a command to reply a message, when the discord bot can detects a keyword in a sentence, it can works, like it can reply "good morning" when it detects keyword in a sentence("Hey, good morning everyone").

However, I added many keywords in command, it happened a problem, when I send a sentence has 2 keywords or above, the command will reply the same amount messages to sender. Such as I set two keywords "good morning" and "have a nice day", when someone send a sentence which has that two keywords, bot will catch that two keywords and reply twice message, right?

But I think that's annoying, has any command can stop it keeps detects keyword when it detected a keyword and replied a message? Like I set two keywords in command, and someone send a sentence with that two keywords, the bot can stop detecting when it detects one keyword, it will just send one reply message, that's I want.

Can someone help me to solve that?
That's my code:

````
async def on_message(msg):
    keyword = ['good morning','great','have a nice day']
    for key in keyword:
        if key in msg.content and key == keyword[0] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_morning = random.choice(jdata['GOODMORNING'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_morning)
        elif key in msg.content and key == keyword[1] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_reaction_1 = random.choice(jdata['REACTION_1'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_reaction_1)
        elif key in msg.content and key == keyword[2] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_reaction_2 = random.choice(jdata['REACTION_2'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_reaction_2)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `break` into each `if` / `elif`. Like this:

```py
async def on_message(msg):
    keyword = ['good morning','great','have a nice day']
    for key in keyword:
        if key in msg.content and key == keyword[0] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_morning = random.choice(jdata['GOODMORNING'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_morning)
            break
        elif key in msg.content and key == keyword[1] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_reaction_1 = random.choice(jdata['REACTION_1'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_reaction_1)
            break
        elif key in msg.content and key == keyword[2] and msg.author != bot.user:
            random_reaction_2 = random.choice(jdata['REACTION_2'])
            await msg.channel.send(random_reaction_2)
            break
```

Comment: You helped me to solved it, thanks bro :D